# Beginner - expanding text view

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, expandablelistview

I'm rather new to application development, and I'm struggling to understand how to make an expandable textView. I need to expand the code below which resides in the xml file:

```
<!-- Clickable title -->
<TextView   android:id="@+id/help_title_guest"
            //style="@style/title_help"
            android:text="Title"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="toggle_contents"/>

<!--content to hide/show -->
<TextView   android:id="@+id/txt_help_gest"
            //style="@style/txt_help"
            android:text="Content"/>
```

I need to expand help_title_guest to show text_help guest once help_title_guest is pressed. The java class which links to this xml file follows below.

```
package com.example.expandinglists;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity{

    private final String TAG = "DemoButton";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove TitleBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //The line below sets the convas / area labelled as activity_main
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        // Remove notification bar.        
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setupMessageButton();

    }

//button Class
    private void setupMessageButton() {
        // Button Functionality
        //1. Get Reference to the button
        Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOnThird);



        //2. Button on Click Listener to run the button related code

        messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //The text below displays a message saying that The button was clicked
                Log.i(TAG, "Application installed");
                Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this,"Application Installed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);

            }           
        });     
    }
//end of button class

}
```

Many thanks in advance,

J

Comment: I fee l you need to use an expandable text view. Check this https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between two TextViews you can put them next to each other horizontally and switch the visibility between VISIBLE and GONE. GONE visibility means that it disappears and takes up no space, which would put the second TextView in its place.